# How to launch an activity in a toolkit library from a separate application

Tags: android

I have a android toolkit with several Views, Activities, and other useful tools. Then when someone would like to use the toolkit, they create their own application, reference the toolkit and get all the goodies. I've gotten this to work for views, but I'm having trouble launching Activities.

Say there is an Activity in the toolkit called BasicHttpServerActivity. How would I launch this activity from a separate application? I've tried using intent filters on the toolkit but I keep getting an error. Here is my current setup.

**Toolkit MANIFEST**

```
<activity android:name=".BasicHttpServerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.fs.BasicHttpServerActivity.LAUNCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Separate application activity launch (attempt)**

```
Intent serverIntent = new Intent("com.fs.BasicHttpServerActivity.LAUNCH");
startActivity(serverIntent);
```

**Logcat says:**

```
04-14 17:16:44.204: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.fs.BasicHttpServerActivity.LAUNCH }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other application would need to add the activity to its manifest. There is no "toolkit manifest".

Comment: Thanks a ton. I just found that in the documentation under using libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any turnaround here to achieve this without including the activity to the base app manifest?

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan: If you package the "toolkit" as an Android library project, there is an option nowadays to do a "manifest merge", where entries in the toolkit's manifest get added to the host application's manifest automatically. I have not tried this, though..